# how to pass the values from txtbox form to sql table

Tags: c#, database-connection

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\hp\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FinalProject\FinalProject\InfoEmp.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserLog where Username = '" + txtUname.Text + "' and Password = '" + txtPword.Text + "' ;", conn);

    SqlDataReader sdr;
    sdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        if (comm.Equals(txtUname.Text) &&
            comm.Equals(txtPword.Text))
        {
            using (frmMain frmmain = new frmMain())
            {
                this.Hide();
                frmmain.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else if (comm.Equals(txtUname.Text) &&
                 comm.Equals(txtPword.Text))
        {
            using (frmMain2 frmmain2 = new frmMain2())
            {
                this.Hide();
                frmmain2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
        else if (txtPword.Text == "" && txtUname.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill in the blanks..");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure that you have access of being admin");
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
```

This is my code .. why in the if else condition .. they reading only the else .. please answer thanks

Comment: you can edit your post ... the format is not shown properly

Comment: what the hell is this?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic error, you need to be using OR operator || for your second "else if" and similar is the case for first "else if". Please look more into SqlCommand documentation for methods related to your use case. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

```
SqlCommand.Equals()
```

would not fit your purpose in this case.